# How can I prevent ggplot2 from overflowing window?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm running R 3.1.1 with ggplot2_1.0.0.  I'm having trouble with the default layout.  I would expect ggplot to do a better job avoiding the overflow you see here.  It feels like ggplot thinks that my device is much larger than it actually is.  I'm running this on Ubuntu 14.04, FWIW.

For something more reproducible, I run this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl,y=hp,color=as.factor(mpg))) + geom_point()
```

And get this, where the legends have really huge boxes.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you think anyone will be able to help at all without some actual code; reproducible code would be best.

Comment: My strong suspicion is that the problem is related to R device params rather than this particular code.  I'll cook up some sample code, but as I said I don't think the code is the key to reproducing the issue.

Comment: Update: Added a code sample with mtcars.

Comment: what do `width` and `height` say from `grDevices::X11.options()`?

Comment: Does this still happen if you close all graphics devices and then run `ggplot()` at the console, letting the default `print` action open a new device? Because I can only get behavior sort of like this (on OS X) if I create a quartz device, resize it to be _very_ small, and then re-run the plot.

Comment: Yes, it still occurs with a new device.

Comment: Well, I think you'll have to find someone who can reproduce this. Because I can't on OS X. It's more likely to be a problem with X11, I would think, than ggplot itself.

Comment: Yeah, I'd buy that explanation, joran.  Thanks for the brain cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. I used the cut argument to specify ranges over mpg. Using cut will automatically coerce the variable to a factor as well.

```
    library(ggplot2)   
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl,y=hp,color=cut(mpg,quantile(mpg,seq(0,1,by=.25))))) + 
    geom_point() + scale_color_discrete(name="Legend Title (mpg breaks)")
```

Comment: The problem isn't so much with transforming the scale as it is an issue of the legend boxes being so large.

Comment: Ahhh. I just suggested it because on my system the boxes don't display like the ones you've attached above. They were all normal sized just too many to bother even having a legend. I think every point had a distinct level.